# sticky footer does not work, background still visible below it

Tags: css

I decided to use the sticky footer solution found in http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/, but I am having trouble implementing it. Specifically, changing the height from anything other than its default `150px` makes the footer fail (the background will appear below it). Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: please post your code and/or a jsfiddle

Comment: The obvious question is of course, did you change all the occurrences of `150px` to your desired values?